# Injecting Spring bean to an outside class created with new()

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to use a spring bean in a Class. I am accessing this class from another spring bean. I have tried to use the `AutoWireCapableBeanFacory` and also the @Configurable + AspectJ LTW, but 'm getting `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` again and again.

My Scenario is as follows :

`ServiceOneImpl` Calls `MyClass`, and `MyClass` uses another bean named `MyService`(autowired)

```
//-------------------ServiceOne--------------
@Service("serviceOne")
public class ServiceOneImpl implements ServiceOne {
   @Override
   public void myMethod() {
       ClassA obj = new ClassA(arg1,arg2);
       obj.doSometing();

   } 
}

//-------------------MyService-------------
@Service("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
   @Override
   public MyDTO getConfiguration(String arg) {
      return myDao.getConfiguration(arg);
   }
}

//-------------------MyClass--------------
@Component
public Class MyClass {

   @Autowired
   private MyService myService;

   private MyDTO myDTO;

   private String mailhost;
   private String arg1;
   private String arg2;

   public A() {
   }

   public A(String param1, String param2) {
       ServletContext context = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
       ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(context);   

       applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().
       autowireBeanProperties(this, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_AUTODETECT,
       true);
       myDTO = myService.getConfiguration(); 
       mailhost = myDTO.getMailhost();

      //Do some process
   }
   public doSometing() {
      //Do some process
   }       
}
```

but i am getting `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` `MyService` is not getting autowired, it returns null value

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at com.beo.atlas.common.filter.ClientSideCacheClearingFilter.doFilter(ClientSideCacheClearingFilter.java:34)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersisten
```

I am using `SpringFramework 4.0.3.RELEASE`

I am unable to fix this issue. It will be immense help for me if somebody pour some light upon me

Thanks in Advance

iMmo

Comment: All these seem to be Spring Beans, so why are you using new? Configure a Factory in the Spring Context instead.

Comment: @Component tag was a mistake from my side, as i thought using it will make it a bean, 
Actually 'MyClass' is a common class and i need to call the class with constructor overloading, and my project lead wants to use it with new MyClass(...) constructors.

Comment: Still I think the cleanest way would be to have a Factory for the class in Spring, which could inject further dependencies in the class.

Comment: See this
[Using ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237062/using-class-forname-but-want-to-autowire-members-of-the-target-class) Option 2

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a strong reason to do so do not use `new` when you want Spring to wire beans to an object. And avoid tying domain classes to Spring.

IMHO, you'd better use a custom builder bean :

```
public class ABuilder {
   @Autowired
   private MyService myService;

   public A getA(String param1, String param2) {
       A a = new A(param1, param2);
       a.setMyDTO(myService.getConfiguration()); 
       a.setMailhost(myDTO.getMailhost());
       return a;
   }
}
```

and modify `ServiceOne` accordingly :

```
//-------------------ServiceOne--------------
@Autowired
ABuilder aBuilder;

@Service("serviceOne")
public class ServiceOneImpl implements ServiceOne {
   @Override
   public void myMethod() {
       ClassA obj = aBuilder.getA(arg1, arg2);
       obj.doSometing();
   } 
}
```

That way,`A` (or `MyClass` or `ClassA`) can have no explicit dependancies on Spring and will be injected with other beans through its builder.

Of course, that is not real code (incoherences in parameters and naming), but yours was not either ...

Comment: Thanks bro for your valuable suggestion.I will take a look onto it and i will definitely try it.
But i got it working with adding @Lazy to the Autowired bean, seems things working at the moment and i dnt think my solution is the apt one, btw i cant use the exact code here, as i fear the proprietary law will make problems for me :)

Answer (score 0):

please add:

```
<context:spring-configured />
```

into your spring configuration,

then add @Configurable at the MyClass class not @Component!

Comment: I have tried it @Configurable
<context:load-time-weaver />
and -javaagent:spring-aspect.jar
but no effect, i have mentioned it in my question

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding @Lazy annotation to the autowired property.

The complete code for future refrence :

```
//-------------------ServiceOne--------------
@Service("serviceOne")
public class ServiceOneImpl implements ServiceOne {
   @Override
   public void myMethod() {
       ClassA obj = new ClassA(arg1,arg2);
       obj.doSometing();

   } 
}

//-------------------MyService-------------
@Service("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
   @Override
   public MyDTO getConfiguration(String arg) {
      return myDao.getConfiguration(arg);
   }
}

//-------------------MyClass--------------
@Component
public Class MyClass {

   @Autowired
   @Lazy
   private MyService myService;

   private MyDTO myDTO;

   private String mailhost;
   private String arg1;
   private String arg2;

   public A() {
   }

   public A(String param1, String param2) {
       ServletContext context = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
       ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(context);   

       applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(this,
                AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_NAME,true);
       myDTO = myService.getConfiguration(); 
       mailhost = myDTO.getMailhost();

      //Do some process
   }
   public doSometing() {
      //Do some process
   }       
}
```

Hope it will help someone :)